# use java packages in databrick scala

Tags: java, scala, databricks

I'm new to databrick and I'm just trying to copy my scala code to databrick notebook.

However, for the imports, everything is fine except

```
import org.apache.spark.util.LongAccumxulator
```

which is a package written in Java,

I know that scala can import java packages, so what is going wrong here?

The error message is:

> notebook:11: error: object LongAccumxulator is not a member of package
>   org.apache.spark.util import org.apache.spark.util.LongAccumxulator

What is the reason for getting this error?

Comment: There are two things in using a "package". First, the "package" itself, should be accessible to your program, which for jvm languages means it should be on your classpath. Only when it is available, you can include it in your program by "importing" it.

Comment: So how can I make it available then I can include it?